# Haskell's ($) is a magic operator?

Tags: haskell

Say I have the following functions:

```
infixr 0 <|

{-# INLINE (<|) #-}
(<|) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f <| x = f x

foo :: a -> (forall b. b -> b) -> a
foo x f = f x
```

The following does not type check:

```
ghci> foo 3 <| id

Couldn't match expected type `forall b. b -> b'
            with actual type `a0 -> a0'
In the second argument of `(<|)', namely `id'
In the expression: f 3 <| id
In an equation for `it': it = f 3 <| id
```

However, `foo 3 $ id` *does*.

The definition of (<|) is (as far as I know) identical to the definition of ($). I pretty much ripped out the definition from the base library sources, and changed every instance of ($) to (<|). Compiler magic?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, there's a small amount of compiler magic around `($)` to handle impredicative types. It was introduced because everyone expects

```
runST $ do
  foo
  bar
  baz
```

to typecheck, but it cannot normally. For more details see [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Status/April07) (search `runST`), this [email](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2010-November/019431.html), and this [email](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/18079). The short of it is that there's actually a special rule in the type-checker specifically for `($)` which gives it the ability to resolve the common case of impredicative types.

Comment: Well, there goes my hope of ever renaming the ($) operator. Thanks anyway :)

You get the check mark as soon as SO lets me...

Comment: Also, unrelated to the answer per se, *good find*. It's hard to notice this particular compiler magic.

Comment: @YellPika Sadly, you're stuck with it if you use too many higher rank types.

Comment: The trac page just says that GHC does left-to-right instantiation, not that it special-cases `($)`. Does it actually only do it for `($)`?

Comment: Here's the email where Simon PJ talks about the impredicativity check and the ($) shortcut http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2010-November/019431.html