# Unsure how to use the `$` function

Tags: haskell, operators, brackets

While trying to write a function for transposing a list of lists, I saw something very curious. I tried:

```
> let abc xs | null (head xs) = [] | otherwise = map head xs : abc $ map tail xs
```

and got an error. Then I tried:

```
> let abc xs | null (head xs) = [] | otherwise = map head xs : abc ( map tail xs )
> abc [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

I was led to believe that the `$` operator can be used instead of the brackets, and that that's more Haskellish. Why am I getting an error?

Comment: Please don't add antagonistic comments like "Little things like this is Haskell bothers me to no end!" to questions.  It doesn't add any useful information!  Every tool, language, etc. has its little traps -- we all understand this.  Let's keep the focus on succinctly describing the issue, so that we can help you solve it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An operator is a function that can be applied in a infix position. So `$` is a function.

In Haskell, you can define your own functions that can be used in infix position - between the arguments. Then you can also define function application precedence and associativity using `infix`, `infixr`, `infixl` - that is, the clues telling the compiler whether to treat `a $ b $ c` as `(a $ b) $ c`, or `a $ (b $ c)`.

The precedence of `$` is such that your first expression is interpreted like `(map head xs : abc) $ ...`

For example, to declare `$` as infix, place its name in `()`:

```
($) :: (a->b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

or composition:

```
(.) :: (b->c)->(a->b)->a->c
(f . g) x = f $ g x
```

Arithemtic "operators" are also defined as infix functions in class Num.

Additionally, you can use other functions as infix, by quoting them in backticks `` at the application site. Sometimes it makes the expression look prettier:

```
f `map` xs == map f xs
```

(not that in this particular case it makes it look pretty, just to show a simple example)

Comment: $ is definitely an operator by the Haskell Report. As is any function with a name consisting entirely of symbols. It is not, however, a special language keyword.

There is also no special magic involved in declaring an operator infix. Whether I define `f $ x = ...` or `($) f x= ...` it is still infix when not enclosed in paranthesis in an expression. The only other way of getting an infix operator in Haskell is by enclosing expressions in `\`\`` such as `\`map\``

Comment: @Sarah ok, I don't know how the report calls it. I wanted to emphasize there is no big difference in what it is.

Comment: That's a good point, it is just a function, but saying that it's not an operator is simply wrong. What you mean is that it's not a special language construct like, say, a keyword.

Comment: One way of putting it might be "`$` is not a keyword, nor it is syntatic sugar".

Comment: Except, of course, [that it is a special language keyword with special typing magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795747/haskells-is-a-magic-operator/20795832#20795832) not that it (almost ever) matters.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson how is it possible to answer the questions correctly without knowing how the compiler works? :) Anyway, that answer seems to imply the compiler treats it specially; I didn't dig the email thread, but does it look at `$` as a symbol, or does it look at the implementation? Eg if I declare a function equivalent to `$`, but call it differently, will that work?

Comment: If you rename it then the impredicative type checking will fail for that aliased symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Sassa's correct answer, let's dissect the code snippet you provided a bit further:

```
map head xs : abc $ map tail xs
```

Two operators are used here: `(:)` and `($)`. As noted above, these are interpreted as infix by default because their names consist only of symbols.

Each operator has a precedence which decides how 'tightly' it binds or, perhaps more usefully, which operator is applied first. Your code could be interpreted either as

```
((map head xs) : abc) $ (map tail xs)
```

where `(:)` binds more tightly (is applied before) `($)` or as

```
(map head xs) : (abc $ (map tail xs))
```

where `($)` binds more tightly. Note that I have put parentheses around function application (for example `map` applied to `tail` and `xs`) as well. Function application binds more tightly than any operator and is thus always applied first.

To decide which of the two ways to interpret the code is correct, the compiler needs to get information about which operator should bind more tightly. This is done using a fixity declaration like

```
infix 8
```

or in general

```
infix i
```

where `i` is between 0 and 9. Higher values of `i` mean that an operator binds more tightly. (`infixr` and `infixl` may be used to additionally define associativity as explained in Sassa's answer, but this doesn't affect your specific problem.)

As it turns out, the fixity declaration for the `($)` operator is

```
infixr 0 $
```

as seen in the [Prelude documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-36-). `(:)` is a bit more 'magic' because it is hard-coded into the Haskell syntax, but the Haskell Report [specifies](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#lists) that it has precedence 5.

Now we finally have enough information to conclude that the first interpretation of your code is indeed correct: the precedence of `(:)`, 5, is higher than the precedence of `($)`, 0. As a general rule of thumb, `($)` often doesn't interact well with other operators.

By the way, if an expression contains two different operators which have the same precedence (such as [`(==)` and `(/=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-61--61-)), the order in which they should be applied is unclear, so you have to use parentheses to specify it explicitly.