# Haskell function application replacing parenthesis

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie here. I'm playing around with this expression:

```
"The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++ (show (3 + 4))
```

Which evaluates fine. This is also fine:

```
"The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++ (show $ 3 + 4)
```

But I get a 'parse error on input $' when I replace the last pair of parenthesis with `$`:

```
"The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++ $ show $ 3 + 4
```

which I'm not really sure why. I'm following the LearnYouAHaskell [series](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application) which says:

> '$ being sort of the equivalent of writing an opening parentheses and
>   then writing a closing one on the far right side of the expression.'

What have I missed?

Comment: Are you looking for `(++) "The sum of 3 and 4 is " $ show $ 3 + 4` ?

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! I wonder why it doesn't work with the infix use of ++ though?

Comment: @xdl You can't have two infix operators next to each other, it's not well defined.  What would `1 + * 2` be?  How would you even interpret that?  The `$` operator is nothing special in Haskell, it's an operator defined just like any other.  It just has a low precedence and associates to the right.

Comment: @bheklilr Isn't there some compiler magic around ``$``? I remember some problems arising when defining an own implementation of ``$``. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795747/haskells-is-a-magic-operator) is a link to the question I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Partially applied infix operators need to be enclosed in parentheses.** So:

```
"The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++ $ show $ 3 + 4
```

fails, but...

```
("The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++) $ show $ 3 + 4
```

works just fine. Note that you could also use the `(.)` function to *compose* the functions, like so:

```
("The sum of 3 and 4 is " ++) . show $ 3 + 4
```

... but that comes later in learn-you-a-haskell.

Also, as @Shanthakumar posted, it might be desirable to do it this way:

```
(++) "The sum of 3 and 4 is " $ show $ 3 + 4
```